# Reading data from Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview, datatable

I've got problem, I'm making application in c# which provides connection to Oracle datebase, and I'm trying to display one table in DataGridView. I'm using VS 2010 and i've got problem with binding data source. the compiler says that even this cast is invalid: "BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();". There's "using System.Windows.Forms;" at the beginning of the code, do you know what problem is it?

I've tried with new project, this time compiler doesn't have problem with that statement, but now with:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from sys.raport", conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

He throws exeception at da.fill(ds), saying the cast is invalid, can you help me?

Edit:
Also tried:
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from sys.raport", conn);

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

But it fails at dataTable.Load(reader);

Comment: Where is OracleConnection object?

Comment: It's opened earlier, and before reading the table i'm executing non-query procedure, which works fine.

Comment: are you sure you are getting `invalid cast` exception in fill method. I would say, error is coming from some other part of code which you have not posted.

Comment: previous part of code:string oradb = "Data Source=XE;User Id=appadmin;Password=appadmin;";

            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb); 
           
                conn.Open();


            OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand("sys.odswiez_raport", conn);

            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();